# Equilateral triangular grid generation algorithm

Tags: partial-differential-equations, algorithms, coordinate-systems

In a research that I'm doing I need to generate an equilateral triangular grid and use this grid to mesh a region of space represented as a polygon to solve a PDE on this mesh. The problem is I need an algorithm to generate the grid and numbering the nodes and the connection table of this nodes, I searched out there in web without any good result. If someone know a good algorithm or had worked on this kind of grids and can help me to figure out a solution it will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first generate a square grid $ℤ×ℤ$, add all diagonals which go from the bottom left corner to the top right corner (i.e. they are parallel to the line from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$) and then apply a linear map which deforms this into a triangular grid.

[image: The image before the transformation]

A possible deformation matrix for this is given by: $\left(\begin{matrix}
  1 & \frac{-1}{2} \\
  0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
 \end{matrix}\right)$.

The coefficients are $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ because those are height and half width respectively of an unit equilateral triangle.

[image: The image after the transformation]

Comment: If I had correctly understand you answer, you are suggesting to apply a shear transformation to a squared grid to get an equilateral triangular grid. In this case I had to transform every point of the grid by mean of the transformation matrix given in your answer ?

Comment: Yes. But it isn't technically a [Shear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping) because of the compression into the $y$ direction. And if you just take a square grid, a lot of edges are missing. I'm don't know what data structure you use for the grid, so I can't suggest any code. If you want, I can generate a picture.

Comment: The information about the nodes coordinates and edges will be stored in database tables, the c++ will be used as programming language. If it is easy to generate a picture it will be good.

Comment: I hope the picture helps. First one shows it before the transformation, the second one is afterwards.

Comment: Ok I see how it works now, i will try to implement it in C++. Thank you